# how do i draw bullet in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i am experiencing problem trying to draw a bullet but it just plain isnt working ,this is the code
i was watching this tutorial   https://youtu.be/FfWpgLFMI7w
i cant find the answer anywhere
the bullet isnt appearing i have tried to replicate tutorial, seach on youtube
i have got the enemy and player moving [image]

```
....
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bacground = pygame.image.load("background.png")




playerimg = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
playerX_change = 0
playerX = 360
playerY = 480
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))

enemyimg = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
enemyX = random.randint(0,736)
enemyY = random.randint(50,150)
enemyX_change = 4
enemyY_change = 40


def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyimg, (x, y))


bulletimg = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
bulletX = playerX
bulletY = playerY
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 40
bullet_state = "ready"

def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 16, y+10))


# drawing player on screen



# game loop
running = True

while running == True:
    screen.fill((200, 200, 0))
    screen.blit(bacground,(0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            player(playerX, playerY)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 5
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            fire_bullet(playerX ,bulletY)
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0


    playerX += playerX_change
    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if bullet_state == "fire" :
        fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    if enemyX>= 736:
        enemyX_change = -4
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
...
```

Comment: You have to update the display after drawing the bullet. Move `pygame.display.update()`.

Comment: where do i have to move it
@rabbid76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rabbid76 already said: *You have to update the display after drawing the bullet.*

Just think a moment about how your code runs:

```
while running:
    screen.fill((200, 200, 0))
    screen.blit(bacground,(0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    pygame.display.update()
    ...
    fire_bullet(playerX ,bulletY)
    ...
```

- You fill the screen
- You draw the background image
- You draw the player
- You draw the enemy
- You update the display and see the background, the player, and the enemy
- You draw the bullet
- You fill the screen
- You draw the background image
- You draw the player
- You draw the enemy
- You update the display and see the background, the player, and the enemy
- You draw the bullet
- You fill the screen
- ...

So, you see, everytime you draw the bullet, you immediately fill the screen and draw the background image over it.

Call `pygame.display.update()` *after* drawing all your images for the frame, not inbetween.